# When sequence was updated in oracle

Tags: oracle, sequence

I've found a gap of 18 numbers in my oracle sequence that appeared during holidays and found no traces of this crime in log files. Can I see somehow a time when sequence is updated or any other way to trace the disappearance of sequence numbers?

Comment: Maybe those 18 records were deleted?. If you had some sort of audit trigger on that table, you might be able to work it out. Why is that a "crime"?

Comment: A gap in the sequence number is not a problem. You can ignore that. The values generated by a sequence are totally meaningless and it does not matter if you use the value 42,60,4546,-35345 or 632023485

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answers/comments state, sequences are never guaranteed to be gap free. Gaps can happen in many ways.

One of the things about sequences are that they default to `CACHE 20`. That means that when `NEXTVAL` is called, the sequence *in the database* is actually increased by 20, the value is returned, and the next 19 values are just returned from memory (the shared pool.)

If the sequence is aged out of the shared pool, or the shared pool is flushed or the database restarted, the values "left over" in the sequence memory cache is lost, as the sequence next time picks up the value from the database, which was 20 higher than last time.

As you state it happened during holidays, I guess it to be a likely cause that your sequence used 2 values from memory, then the DBA did maintenance in the holidays that caused the shared pool to flush, and the remaining 18 values in the sequence memory cache is gone.

That is normal behaviour and the reason why sequences work fast. You can get "closer" to gap-free by `NOCACHE NOORDER`, but it will cost performance and never be quite gap-free anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A sequence is not guaranteed to produce a gap free sequence of numbers. It is used to produce a series of (unique) numbers that is highly scalable in a multi-user environment.

If your application requires that some numeric identifier on a table is sequential without gaps then you will need another way of generating those identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The oracle sequence are `NOORDER` in default. please refer the oracle documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm . hence `NOORDER` behavior cannot be as expected. You can check whether your oracle sequence is in `ORDER` if not then it is some other problem.